# Password and music

Tags: password, music

1. It has been so long that I have used my password for administrator, how can I reset it?
   or do without it?
2. Why doesn't the music play on a Power Point presentation?

Comment: Hi -- need to make these separate questions, please.   Need more details on what works, doesn't work for sound, music, etc. for the second one.

Comment: 1st question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password?rq=1